# Replace string by sed with double quota (special characters)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to change **fileSystem: "/test/test"** to **fileSystem: "/apptest"** in RHEL6 and i tried to use :

```
sed -i 's/fileSystem: "/test/test"/fileSystem: "/apptest"' text.txt
```

but doesnt work, output  :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unknown option to `s'
```

I have no idea how to change it. I read some documents but didnt find out how to work.

Can you help me?

Regards.

Comment: change the sed separator or escape le `/` in the paths

Answer (score 2):

Because your string itself contains `/` characters, you should use a different delimiter for the `s` command. For example, `#`:

```
sed -i 's#fileSystem: "/test/test"#fileSystem: "/apptest"#' text.txt
```

(You were also missing the delimiter after the replacement.)

Comment: Thank you its working :).

One more question - i want to put read command like :

read fs?"Please provide pathname : "

sed -i 's#fileSystem: "/test/test"#fileSystem: "$fs"#' text.txt

but doesnt work.
Can you advice me how to use variable inside above sed commend? Should I change somehow above command?

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes. Replace the single quotes `'` by double quotes `"` and then escape the double quotes _inside_ the string using `\"`.